# How does the Allison (now Rolls-Royce) CX-31 centrifugal compressor achieve a pressure ratio of 10?

Tags: engine-design, compressor

Centrifugal compressors typically have pressure ratios up to around 7 or 8.  But Rolls-Royce has a graphic showing the evolution of their line of small turboshaft engines that shows the compressors and their OPRs, which shows a compressor called "CX-31," which they say had a pressure ratio of TEN.

I've searched for months for any info on this compressor but have never found a single hit. Internet shows no record of this compressor being used in any engine, either production or test. Of course that could be due to any number of problems, like stall margin or production cost.

How do they achieve a pressure ratio of 10 with this compressor?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! I changed your question a bit to ask a more specific question. I hope this is what you were interested in (if not, feel free to edit again). Generic questions don't work well on this site (also see the [Tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site).